# add new item to CHtml in yii

Tags: yii, doctrine-orm, yii-chtml

I work Yii with doctrine 2. I have a problem, datetime in doctrine 2 is an object of DateTime class, and I can't update it with regular methods of CHtml or form.

How can I add new item in CHtml that can handle this situation.

--Best Regards
Moe Far

Comment: please add code that you've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the `CHtml` class and add your own functions. The code should look something like this:

```
class MyHtml extends CHtml {
    // add you own logic or override CHtml functions

    public static function myFunction() {
        return 'yeah!'; 
    }
}
```

You can then use `MyHtml::myFunction()` and also use all the standard CHtml functions.

Take a look at this question for more info on extending classes in Yii: [How to extend Yii framework classes and where to place the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451935/how-to-extend-yii-framework-classes-and-where-to-place-the-files)

Comment: Thnx jagsler, I also want to make a new element in cactiveform to manage my data model with it. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: No problem. If this is the correct answer you should mark it btw. Not really sure what you want to do with de `CActiveForm` but you can also extend this class and create `MyActiveForm` (or some name) and add your own logic.